# Nginx throwing 404 error while accessing assets folder

Tags: angular, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

through api call loading one json file, but it is throwing index.html file

```
server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;
        root         /var/www/html/nginx-sample;
        index index.html
       
        location  / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
```

and I tried below approach now it is throwing 404

```
server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;
        root         /var/www/html/nginx-sample;
        index index.html
        location /assets/ {
                root /var/www/html/nginx-sample/assets;
        }
        location  / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
```